# DataContract serializer support for imports. Out of band mechanism?

Tags: .net, wcf, datacontractserializer

Describing the DataContractSerializers support for import msdn has this to say:

Supported. DataContractSerializer supports xs:include and xs:import. However, Svcutil.exe restricts following xs:include/@schemaLocation and xs:import/@location references when metadata is loaded from a local file. The list of schema files must be passed through an out-of-band mechanism and not through include in this case; included schema documents are ignored.

What does "out-of-band mechanism" mean? There seems to be no other mention of this in the document.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733112.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that in this case ("when metadata is loaded from a local file"), you need to manually download all your schema files and supply them on the svcutil.exe command line; It will not automatically follow links for you.

Comment: thanks for this, have been doing as you say without knowing what it meant. Seems a strange omission to me.